# how to run control m job through python script?

Tags: python, shell, control-m

i have a control m job instead of triggering it through control m application i want to trigger through my python script but i don't know how to perform this action is there any module available in python which can trigger control m job and also how can I pass user-id , DNS details and password into it..

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using Control-M Automation API.
You can use the following link as a reference for the python code:

https://github.com/controlm/automation-api-quickstart/tree/master/control-m/201-call-rest-api-using-python

You can use the following link to browse the Control-M Swagger documentation:

http://aapi-swagger-doc.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/#/run/runNow

It seems like `/run/runNow` endpoint will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Since the time the other answer was given, suggesting to call REST APIs from Python, a python package has been published.

With the python package, you create Python objects (classes) for the Folder, jobs, and then run it, all directly from Python. Have a look at
https://controlm.github.io/ctm-python-client/
for more information.

It allows your code to be more structured, and it is simpler to program it with loops and branches, parameters, and so on.